# Mass wrap html-files and save in utf-8

Tags: encoding, sublimetext3, editing

I exported apple notes to html files by Automator scripts. I need them in HTML to import in Notion.

There are 2 main problems:

1. Files saved with wrong encoding, need to save in UTF-8
2. There's no `<html>, <head>, <body>` tags.

There are many of them, so can't edit them manually.

Files look like that

```
<div>some text</div>
<div>another line</div>
```

Is there any way I could do this in Sublime Text 3 or with terminal?